# Disable touch events in phonegap (xcode iOS)

Tags: android, ios, jquery-mobile, cordova, touch

I am having the most annoying situation. Ok, here goes. I am using a javascript based sliding menu for a mobile app. The "slider" works just like Facebook mobile, where you can click the button to show the menu on the left and click it again to close the menu. As an alternative, if you touch the still visible part of the page when the menu is showing it will also close. And that's it.

Problem: Note that I'm using Phonegap for this app. When I run the iOS simulator in Xcode all works fine EXCEPT if you swipeleft, for example, the page will move. I want to disable the swipe event all together. I have tried preventDefault, return false etc. Nothing seems to work. Again, my only goal is to disable touch events because for this app, I simply don't need them. Please see the javascript code for the menu show/hide below.

Thanks is advance. All is appreciated.

```js
$(function(){
var menuStatus;     

// Show menu
$("a.showMenu").click(function(){

$('#menu').show();
    if(menuStatus != true){

    $(".ui-page-active").animate({
        marginLeft: "170px",

      }, 300, function(){menuStatus = true});
      return false;
      } else {

        $(".ui-page-active").animate({
            marginLeft: "0px",
      }, 300, function(){menuStatus = false});
        return false;
      }
});

// Menu behaviour
$("#menu li a").click(function(){
    var p = $(this).parent();
    if($(p).hasClass('active')){
        $("#menu li").removeClass('active');
    } else {
        $("#menu li").removeClass('active');
        $(p).addClass('active');
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could over-ride the `$.event.special.swipe.horizontalDistanceThreshold` to a larger value and prevent swipes on your page from triggering the swipe event.

Refer to [Touch Events -> Swipe](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html)

Comment: Oh so in essence I could override the default horizontalDistanceThreshold of 30 and set it to something really large like say 9999, which obviously can't be reached on an iPhone device... As a result the swipe event would never be triggered, right?

Comment: Hello Nirmal, thanks for the response. I tried your suggestion but unfortunately it didn't solve the issue. Actually I just want to disable all touch events - e.g. swipe, drag etc.Not sure if this makes sense.

Comment: Hi Nirmal, Again thank you for your help. I think I may have figured it out. I used the below code to disable the touch events. Actually, it was my bad for not being clear. It was touchmove that I was most concerned with. $(document).on('touchmove', function(e) {

 e.preventDefault();
 return false;

});

Comment: Needless to say, I should also be able to add that to specific elements. Thanks alot for guiding me in the right direction. - EA

Comment: In case you are actually trying to disable touch events alltogether; you could try using the JQueryMobile Download Builder tool to create a JQM version without including Touch events.